# Why does the last def overwrite any previous defs in this clojure code?

Tags: clojure

Consider this code -

```
(defn make-getter
  [pred]
  (defn getter
    [db-name htree-name]
    (filter pred (HTreeMap. db-name htree-name))))

(def meta-data-key? #(= (.getKey %) "META_DATA"))
(def not-meta-data-key? #(not (= (.getKey %) "META_DATA")))

(def get-type (make-getter meta-data-key?))
(def get-records (make-getter not-meta-data-key?))
```

HTreeMap is a java class implementing the Map interface on top of a JDBM HTree. There are two kinds of records in the map - those whose key is "META_DATA" and the rest. What the get-type function should return is only the entry with "META_DATA" key and get-records should return everything except the entry with the "META_DATA" key. But if get-type is now called it returns even those records whose getKey() != "META_DATA". If I change the order of get-type and get-records to

```
(def get-records (make-getter not-meta-data-key?))
(def get-type (make-getter meta-data-key?))
```

then both functions return only those records whose getKey() == "META_DATA". Why is the definition of an already defined function overwritten by the one defined later?

Comment: You have only the one instance of `getter` function at time. You should use anonymous function definition instead of `defn getter`.

Comment: FYI: `(def not-meta-data-key? (complement meta-data-key?))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Clojure docs](http://clojure.org/special_forms#def):

> Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of symbol and a namespace of the value of the current namespace (*ns*).

So every time you call `make-getter`, new **global** function is defined. Of course, there may be only one global function with such name in current namespace, so all previous bindings are overwritten.

What you actually want is **returning anonymous** closure instead of **defining** function:

```
(defn make-getter
  [pred]
  (fn
    [db-name htree-name]
    (filter pred (HTreeMap. db-name htree-name))))
```

This way `get-records` and `get-types` will be initialized with 2 different closure objects (same anonymous function, but with different bound predicates).

Answer (score 3):

This is more an addition to @ffriend's answer, which is correct. I just think, that it needs a few clarifications, which wasn't quite suitable for a comment.

`(defn f [x] body...)` is roughly equivalent to `(def f (fn [x] body...))`. That is, creating a function and assigning it as the value of `f`. The main problem with your code lies in the fact that `defn` (like `def`) returns the symbol, rather than its value. That is:

```
user=> (defn getter
           [db-name htree-name]
           (filter pred (HTreeMap. db-name htree-name)))
; => #'user/getter
```

(you'll have the current namespace instead of `user`)

And so, your consequent definitions of `get-type` and `get-records` makes their values the symbol `#'user/getter`:

```
user=> getter
; => #<user$getter user$getter@f491ac9>
user=> get-type
; => #'user/getter
user=> get-records
; => #'user/getter
```

They'll effectively act as aliases to the `getter` function.

Add to that the fact, that you redefine `getter`'s value with each call to `make-getter` and you see why you always get the latest definition.

The correct way to fix this is, to define `make-getter` using `fn` instead of `defn`:

```
(defn make-getter
  [pred]
  (fn
    [db-name htree-name]
    (filter pred (HTreeMap. db-name htree-name))))
```

Or you can go on and create a macro `defgetter` like this (not well tested):

```
(defmacro def-getter
  [name pred]
  `(def ~name (make-getter [~pred])))
```

And use it like this:

```
#user=> (def-getter get-type meta-data-key?)
; => #'user/get-type
#user=> (def-getter get-records not-meta-data-key?)
; => #'user/get-records
```